# Cannot connect Studio 3t for MongoDB v2.4.6 via SSH

Tags: mongodb, connection, sunos, studio3t

I have SunOS and I am trying to connect from Studio 3T on Windows. I cannot connect and get the following error in the log:

> Database error(MongoIncompatibleDriverException): Server at
>   xx.xx.xx.xx:27017 reports wire version 0, but this version of the
>   driver requires atleast 1 (MongoDB 2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Studio 3T upgraded to the latest 3.6 mongo driver back in December 2017, which seems to have dropped support for MongoDB 2.4 (it reached its End-Of-Life in March 2016: https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy).

With this change, Studio 3T then currently supports MongoDB versions 2.6 - 3.6.